# Is it possible to return multiple types through a function?

Tags: c++11

I wanted to know if its possible to return a function that could either return a boolean or a void ? I know I could use `std::optional` however that is available only in C++17 and my code base is C++11. I would like something like this

```
xxx process(int a)
{
 if (a==1) 
    return true;
 if (a==2) 
    return false;
 if (a==3)
    .... //return nothing
}
```

Comment: Aside from the (correct) *technical* answer by Alexcei below... your example code smacks of *really* bad design. That might be just because it's a quick and dirty example, but as the caller of your function I would very much prefer to *know* the type returned without much checking. In other words, the *caller* code would look very much like the one in your function -- is it `true`, or `false`, or "nothing"? -- and then what good did your function do if the caller has to, effectively, repeat the test? Of course, it might just be a bad example of what you want, so feel free to ignore me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For returning two values I use a std::pair (usually typedef'd). 
In C++11 and newer, you should use [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) for more than two return results.

The **abstract** example using the tuple

```
std::tuple<bool, int> process(int a)
{
 if (a==1) 
    return std::make_tuple(true, 0);
 if (a==2) 
    return std::make_tuple(false, 0);
 if (a==3)
    return std::make_tuple(false, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant might be a better match:

According to your requirement: a function that could either return a boolean or a void

See at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

> The class template std::variant represents a type-safe union. An
>   instance of std::variant at any given time either holds a value of one
>   of its alternative types, or it holds no value (this state is hard to
>   achieve, see valueless_by_exception).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write an equivalent of std::optional yourself use an enum.

```
enum class Result
{
    False,
    True,
    Nothing // or whatever name makes sense in your use case
};
```